# Unable to hide overflow for x axis and show overflow for y axis

Tags: html, css

I have the following where I am able to `hide overflow` for `y axis`.

And `show overflow` for `x axis`.

```html
    <style type="text/css">
      #outer-wrapper {
        overflow-y: hidden;
      }
      #outer {
        width:100px;
        height:100px;
        background:red;
        border:solid red 1px;
        overflow-x: visible;
      }
      #inner {
        width:300px;
        height:300px;
        background:green;
      }
    </style>
    <div id="outer-wrapper">
      <div id="outer">
        <div id="inner"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

I want this to be in inverse where I can `hide overflow` for `x axis`.

And `show overflow` for `y axis`.

Thus tried the following.

But result is the same, Y axis is still hidden and X axis is still overflowing. Why?

```html
    <style type="text/css">
      #outer-wrapper {
        overflow-x: hidden;
      }
      #outer {
        width:100px;
        height:100px;
        background:red;
        border:solid red 1px;
        overflow-y: visible;
      }
      #inner {
        width:300px;
        height:300px;
        background:green;
      }
    </style>
    <div id="outer-wrapper">
      <div id="outer">
        <div id="inner"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Also tried following. Here I am able to hide X axis as intended.

But now Y axis is hidden too which is wrong.

```html
    <style type="text/css">
      #outer-wrapper {
        overflow-x: hidden;
      }
      #outer {
        width:100px;
        height:100px;
        background:red;
        border:solid red 1px;
        overflow-y: visible;
        overflow-y: hidden;
      }
      #inner {
        width:300px;
        height:300px;
        background:green;
      }
    </style>
    <div id="outer-wrapper">
      <div id="outer">
        <div id="inner"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: There are two overflow-y in #outer, last code, is that right? Maybe it's the problem.

Comment: the overflow only works if it's clear what the dimensions of the container are.  You didn't set them. The answer from @Fabricio B should do what you wanted.

Answer (score 1):

That can be useful:

```
 <style type="text/css">
     
      #outer {
        width:100px;
        height:100px;
        background:red;
        border:solid red 1px;
        overflow-y: auto;  //shows the y axis
        overflow-x: hidden; //hiddens the x axis
      }

      #inner {
        width:300px;
        height:300px;
        background:green;
      }

    </style>


    <div id="outer-wrapper">
      <div id="outer">
        <div id="inner"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Please run your code. This hides both X and Y axis overflows.
X axis is supposed to be hidden and Y axis is suppose to be visible.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like so by adding only on `#outer` an `overflow-y : visible` and an `overflow-x: hidden`:

```html
<style type="text/css">
 
  #outer {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background:red;
    border:solid red 1px;
   /* all you need*/
    overflow-y: visible;
    overflow-x: hidden;
  }
  #inner {
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
    background:green;
  }
</style>
<div id="outer-wrapper">
  <div id="outer">
    <div id="inner"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: By doing above, y axis overflow gets hidden too. Y should overflow, x should stay hidden.

Answer (score 0):

```
<style>
  #outer-example {
    overflow-x: hidden;
  }
  #outer {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    overflow-y: visible;
  }
  #inner {
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
   }
</style>
<div id="outer-example">
  <div id="outer">
    <div id="inner"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please run your code. This hides both X and Y axis overflows.
X axis is supposed to be hidden and Y axis is suppose to be visible.